# Does XMLHttpRequest accept the file protocol?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to make a react native application that requires converting a file on the local device into a javascript File object or Blob, but it has an address using the file:// protocol. According to this [Medium article,](https://medium.com/@joananespina/uploading-to-firebase-storage-with-react-native-39f4a500dbcb) you can use XMLHttpRequest to turn the URI into a Blob:

```
uriToBlob = (uri) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function() {
         // return the blob
         resolve(xhr.response);
      };

      xhr.onerror = function() {
      // something went wrong
      reject(new Error('uriToBlob failed'));
   };

   // this helps us get a blob
   xhr.responseType = 'blob';
   xhr.open('GET', uri, true);

   xhr.send(null);
   });
}
```

I am wondering how this is possible and if someone could give an explanation, considering that the URI doesn't use HTTP protocol? According to whatever documentation I could find, XMLHttpRequest is only used for HTTP requests to a server?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it fail? If yes, what error?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Reference the section on "Handling binary data"

You can use it against file: but progress listeners are not supported... so you'll only be able to trigger on load, error, and abort

Comment: The file is located on a local device, not on a server. My question boils down to if/how XMLHttpRequest can take File:// URI's instead of HTTP URL's, since it never seems to be mentioned in the documentation. I'm not concerned with whether or not it is read as binary or textual data.

Answer (score 0):

XHR sets the *request*'s mode to "CORS" <sup>[ [permalink](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method), [templink](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-concept-request-mode) ]</sup>

So are allowed only <sup>([permalink](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#main-fetch))</sup>

- *same-origin* requests (includes `blob://` scheme). <sup>[[templink](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-concept-request-current-url%E2%91%A0%E2%91%A2)]</sup>
- `data://` schemes <sup>[[templink](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-concept-request-current-url%E2%91%A0%E2%91%A3)]</sup>
- [`HTTP(s)-schemes`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-scheme) <sup>[[templink](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-concept-request-current-url%E2%91%A0%E2%91%A4) ]</sup>

Now, browsers don't all agree as to how `file://` origins should relate with each others. Some like Chrome will consider it an *opaque-origin*, and will thus never treat it as *same-origin*  and you won't be able to fetch from this scheme in this browser*.
In Firefox, they will consider that any resource in the same directory or deeper in the FileSystem is *same-origin*, so there you can fetch it.
Also, some have security lifts available where they may exceptionally allow scripts to access it, for instance starting Chrome with the [--allow-file-access-from-files](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#allow-file-access-from-files) will allow requests from a `file://` scheme to perform such requests.